# Collect Data from DBMS_PIPE using Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am currently working on a project where a lot of users will be making changes to our data and that  rest of the clients are suppose to see data as soon as it updates. I have implemented web sockets to broadcasting the data the problem is we are using Oracle DBMS_PIPE as whenever data is changed in the DB now I was wondering if there is some api or some documentation which tell how to collect data from DBMS_PIPE using Java. any suggestions?

Thank you

F. Irfan